# How do I fix my unit test methods when using auto generated test classes by InteliTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, pex

I am trying to understand `automated` test class generation in Visual Studio. I am using `Microsoft Plex Framework`. Here is the details of Pex framework. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/pex-and-moles-isolation-and-white-box-unit-testing-for-net/

I have used the code as shown below

```
public class AuditRepository:BaseDataRepository<AuditItem, int>, IAuditRepository
{
    public AuditRepository(string connString, IContainerFactory containerFactory) : base(connString, containerFactory)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable GetTopAudit(int topCount)
    {
        const string sql = "SELECT TOP ({0}) * FROM audit ORDER BY CreatedTime DESC";
        return Query(string.Format(sql, topCount));
    }
}
```

I have used `InteliTest` to create `unit test` for above method and which automatically generated the `test files and methods` as shown below

```
/// <summary>This class contains parameterized unit tests for AuditRepository</summary>
[PexClass(typeof(AuditRepository))]
[PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
[PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(ArgumentException), AcceptExceptionSubtypes = true)]
[TestClass]
public partial class AuditRepositoryTest
{
    /// <summary>Test stub for GetTopAudit(Int32)</summary>
    [PexMethod]
    public IEnumerable GetTopAuditTest([PexAssumeUnderTest]AuditRepository target, int topCount)
    {
        IEnumerable result = target.GetTopAudit(topCount);
        return result;
        // TODO: add assertions to method AuditRepositoryTest.GetTopTest(AuditRepository, Int32)
    }
}
```

Now, when I tried to run the test using `InteliTest` , it shows warnings and suggested to fix by adding below code [Basically below code generated when clicked on 'Fix' button]

```
public static partial class AuditRepositoryFactory
{
    /// <summary>A factory for Radiometer.RadCon.RAP.Repository.AuditRepository instances</summary>
    [PexFactoryMethod(typeof(AuditRepository))]
    public static AuditRepository Create(string connString_s, IContainerFactory containerFactory_iContainerFactory)
    {
        AuditRepository auditRepository
           = new AuditRepository(connString_s, containerFactory_iContainerFactory);
        return auditRepository;

        // TODO: Edit factory method of AuditRepository
        // This method should be able to configure the object in all possible ways.
        // Add as many parameters as needed,
        // and assign their values to each field by using the API.
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand what's going on behind the screen, what does it mean by below commented lines

> // TODO: Edit factory method of AuditRepository
>
> // This method should be able to configure the object in all possible ways.
>
> // Add as many parameters as needed,
>
> // and assign their values to each field by using the API.

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand what a factory pattern is for?

The comments are making suggestions on how to create a factory method.  Code generation is not clever enough to know how you want to usethis function, so the comments are giving you hints.

BTW, you should probably be returning an interface from your factory method, to make testing easier.

```
public static IAuditRepository Create(string connString_s, IContainerFactory containerFactory_iContainerFactory)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Understood slightly. but where do I call AuditRepositoryFactory to get the repository ? if it's inside AuditRepositoryTest, then how?

Comment: Tests should test one class.  If you are testing the factory, then you should just, call the `Create` function and test the result.   If you are testing the repository, just new one up and test that.   If you have other code that calls the factory method, then your factory should not be static, but the interface should be injected into the constructor that calls the factory.